# PDO Search Engine?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created a search feature for my website prior to me rewriting in PDO. I'm incredibly new to both PHP and PDO for use with a MySQL database, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to translate this code, to PDO. I would appreciate someone talking me through it slightly, to help me learn.

My current code is:

```
function doSearch() {
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' or description LIKE '%$searchq%' or content LIKE '%$searchq%'";
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0) {
            $output = '<tr><tr>No results found.</tr></td>';
        } else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $eName = $row['name'];
                $eDesc = $row['description'];
                $eCont = $row['content'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $elvl = $row['level'];
                $ehp = $row['hp'];

                $output .= '<tr><td><a href="http://xxxx.com/xxx?id=' .$id. '" onclick="document.linkform.submit();">'.$eName.'</a></td><td>'.$eDesc.'</td><td>'.$elvl.'</td><td>'.$ehp.'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    return $output;
    }
 }
```

A PDO connection has been made, and it appears to be successful. This is in my functions.php file, and my connection.php file has been attached to functions.php.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? Since you are accepting user values, you should use `prepare()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php and use bound parameters to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
 $conn='';  
    try { 
         $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
 } 
catch (PDOException $e) { 
exit('Database error.'); 
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name LIKE :searchq or description LIKE :searchq or content LIKE :searchq";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":searchq",$searchq,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
 if($count == 0) {
            $output = '<tr><tr>No results found.</tr></td>';
        } else {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $eName = $row['name'];
                $eDesc = $row['description'];
                $eCont = $row['content'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $elvl = $row['level'];
                $ehp = $row['hp'];

                $output .= '<tr><td><a href="http://xxxx.com/xxx?id=' .$id. '" onclick="document.linkform.submit();">'.$eName.'</a></td><td>'.$eDesc.'</td><td>'.$elvl.'</td><td>'.$ehp.'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick. However now I'm getting the following error:

Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in xxxx on line 11.

Comment: @JackMiller It appears that the connection may not have been set correctly. Could you embed connection in a try..catch block and see if an error is thrown?

Comment: Hi, 

I have this currently in my connections.php file:

<?php
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 exit('Database error.');
 }
?>

And I have it included in my functions.php.

Comment: $conn is out of scope here , you need to add the code like I am adding in my code ,